# count how many people join in 1st half and 2nd half

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

[image]

```
import csv


result = {}


 with open('1000 Records.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
    
   csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
    
      for row in csv_reader:
        
         year_of_joining = row[17]
        
         half_of_joining = row[16]
        
         if not year_of_joining in result:
            
            result[year_of_joining] = {half_of_joining: half_of_joining}
        
        else:
            
            result[year_of_joining].update({half_of_joining: half_of_joining})
```

the output I want that is like in the year 1980 people who join in 1st half and 2nd half in dictionary form

like this {1980:{H1:3, H2:0}, 1981:{H1:7, H2:8},.....}

Comment: You might want to look at examples of `defaultdict(int)`

Comment: In any case, can you please explain what you're expecting `{half_of_joining: half_of_joining}` to do? Because that's certainly not counting anything

Comment: i want to count how many people join in h1 and h2 each year if anyone is not available then a default value like 0.

Comment: I understand what you want, but trying to understand your current approach. For example, where in your logic are you doing any sum or a default value of 0?

Comment: sorry man I am new to python can you help me in this ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close, but you need to set `0` somewhere, and accumulate some results

```
import csv

result = {}

with open('records.csv') as csv_file:
  csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
  for row in csv_reader: 
        
    year_of_joining = int(row['Year of Join'])
    half_of_joining = row['Half of Join']

    
    if year_of_joining not in result:
      result[year_of_joining] = {'H1': 0, 'H2': 0}
        
    result[year_of_joining][half_of_joining] += 1
```

Comment: bro what if I want to count males and females separately ??? should I add another if condition to check f and m. it's fine ???

Comment: Please create a new post for new questions. But overall, I suggest you use pandas for any further data analysis that can easily be done with SQL queries

Comment: bro https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67823670/count-male-and-female-quater-seprately