# Count male and female quarters separately

Tags: python, csv

[image]

The result i want that is like this

```
(males {1990: {Q1:value, Q2:value, Q3:Value, Q4: Value}, 
 females {Q1:value, Q2:value, Q3:Value, Q4:value})
```

if anyone value is not there then default value 0

```
import csv
male_count = {}
female_count = {}


 with open('1000 Records.csv') as csv_file:
    
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
    for row in csv_reader:
        
        year_of_joining = int(row[17])
        quarter_of_joining = row[15]
        gender = row[5]
        
        if year_of_joining not in female_count and gender == 'F':
            female_count[year_of_joining] = {'Q1': 0, 'Q2': 0, 'Q3': 0, 'Q4': 0}
            female_count[year_of_joining][quarter_of_joining] = 1
        elif year_of_joining in female_count and gender == 'F':
            female_count[year_of_joining][quarter_of_joining] += 1

        if year_of_joining not in male_count and gender == 'M':
            male_count[year_of_joining] = {'Q1': 0, 'Q2': 0, 'Q3': 0, 'Q4': 0}
            male_count[year_of_joining][quarter_of_joining] = 1
        elif year_of_joining in male_count and gender == 'M':
            male_count[year_of_joining][quarter_of_joining] += 1
print(male_count)
print(female_count)
```

Comment: I suggest using `pandas` and its `groupby` method.

Comment: Why do you have a year in your `males` result, but not in `females`?

Comment: How do you know it doesn't work? See [ask] and how to create a [mcve]. Edit the question.

Comment: because the year is a key and male and female is a value of it and then male and female also work as a key

Comment: it will work but in a different format. I need result in different format

Comment: It would be useful if you showed how your code output differs from what you expect, because it seems like it should work fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want separate dictionaries, and not "gender, grouped by year" (meaning the year is the top-level key of two gender dictionaries), the answer is basically the same as your last question, except you have two separate "`result`" dicts (which you can combine since Python objects are references)

```
import csv

males = {}
females = {}

with open('records.csv') as csv_file:
  csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
  for row in csv_reader: 
        
    year_of_joining = int(row['Year of Join'])
    quarter_of_joining = row['Quarter of Join']
    gender = row['Gender']
    result = males if gender == 'M' else females
    
    if year_of_joining not in result:
      result[year_of_joining] = {f'Q{i+1}': 0 for i in range(4)}
        
    result[year_of_joining][quarter_of_joining] += 1

final_result = {"males": males, "females": females}
```

---

**Input**

```
Gender,Year of Join,Quarter of Join
F,2010,Q1
M,2010,Q2
F,2017,Q1
```

**Output**

```
from pprint import pprint
print('males', end=' ')
pprint(males)
print('females', end=' ')
pprint(females)
```

```
males {2010: {'Q1': 0, 'Q2': 1, 'Q3': 0, 'Q4': 0}}
females {2010: {'Q1': 1, 'Q2': 0, 'Q3': 0, 'Q4': 0},
 2017: {'Q1': 1, 'Q2': 0, 'Q3': 0, 'Q4': 0}}
```

Comment: bro can we used 1 dict in the place of males and female dict in this ??? everything go in that 1 dict

Comment: I don't know your requirements, but of course you can. Start with `result = {'males': dict(), 'females': dict()}`, then check `if year_of_joining not in result[full_gender]`, for example. The rest of the logic should be the same

Comment: You could also simply modify my answer to create one dictionary around the two other dictionaries, after the loop

Comment: can you modify your answer this way

Comment: bro I try what you said but unable to do so please help me. I need the same thing but with 1 dict(result = { })  not 2 dict like (male ={}, females = {} ) all the data of male and female goes into result dict and then i just print them

Comment: Added `final_result = {"males": males, "females": females}`

Answer (score 2):

Using pandas library will make it very easy for you

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('1000 Records.csv', dtype = {"year_of_joining":"category", "quarter_of_joining":"category"})

df_out = df.groupby(index=["Gender", "year_of_joining", "quarter_of_joining"], values="gender", aggfunc="count"]

out_dict = df_out.to_dict()
```

Comment: WIll this add the zero values for missing quarters?

Comment: Not pretty sure but I think the answer is yes. If not, you can add df_out["Gender"] = df_out["Gender"].fillna(0) before defining the out_dict

Comment: I am very grateful for your help but I don't want to use pandas thanks for your help